# Gráfica en R, binomial y normal

Tags: r, rstudio

yo necesito hacer dos gráficas de una binomial y de una normal.

```
nn<-pnorm(c(5.5, 4.5), mean = u, sd = desv)

dbinom(5,100,0.1)
```

Necesito dibujar gráficas de la función de probabilidad de ambas distribuciones.
He intentado con las funciones básicas pero me va solamente la normal la binomial no. ¿Que hago?

Comment: Algo así: `barplot(dbinom(x=0:5,size=100,prob=0.1))`? deberías indicar específicamente que problema tienes con la binomial.

Answer (score 1):

adjunto mi aporte. Espero te ayude en algo.

```
 #introducir el código aquí

 library(ggplot2)
 #Tratamiento de la data para una distribución 
 #normal.
 a<- mean(c(5.5, 4.5))
 sd<-sd(c(5.5,4.5))
 set.seed(123)
 b<-rnorm(1000, mean = a, sd)

 #Visualización de la distribución normal
 ggplot(as.data.frame(b), mapping = aes(b))+
    geom_density(kernel="gaussian", color="coral")+
    labs(title = "Desnsidad de Probabilidad Normal")

 #Tratamiento de la data binomial
 set.seed(123)
 bin<-rbinom(5, size=100, prob = 0.1)

 #Visualización de la distribución binomial
 ggplot(as.data.frame(bin), mapping = aes(bin))+
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01, 
    color="firebrick3", fill="firebrick3")+
    labs(title = "Histograma binomial")

 [introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]


 [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]] 
 [2][![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] 
 [3]][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMppA.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKM94.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI8YJ.png
```

Comment: No estaría mal que explicaras tu aporte, así como también verificar que tus imágenes que tratas de mostrar no se mezclen con el código para que se puedan visualizar.

Comment: **b) Pintar las gracas de la funcióon de probabilidad de ambas distribuciones para el ejemplo anterior, con R o con Rcmdr.**

Comment: Hola, eso se pide para hacer. Hago la misma `dbinom(5,100,0.1)`  y `u<- 100*0.1
desv<-sqrt(100*(0.1*0.9))
nn<-pnorm(c(5.5, 4.5), mean = u, sd = desv)` para hacer la comparación y me sale "iguales". Lo que quería era pintar ambas distribuciones.